# Using OpenCV with PyPy

Tags: python, opencv, pypy

I am trying to run a python script using OpenCV with PyPy, but all the documentation that I found didn't work.

The installation of PyPy went well, but when I try to run the script it says that it can't find OpenCV modules like 'cv2' for example, despite having cloned opencv for pypy directly from a github repository.

I would need to know how to do it exactly.

Comment: are you using python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install opencv-python` worked well for me on python 2.7, I can import and use cv2.

Comment: I am currently using python 2.7, and PyPy 2.7 as the project interpreter with Pycharm. However upon using your command it gives me this error: ```Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 with venv. In PyCharm, go to settings, project interpreter, and hit the "+" button on the right. Here you can add packages to your project interpreter. Search opencv-python and download it. It worked well for me, I use template matching in my project and I'm doing this

Comment: Are you doing all of this while having your project interpreter as PyPy 2.7?, doing what you say gives me the error I talked before, could not find a version that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Nope I'm actually using Python 2.7 (venv) interpreter, I'll try with PyPy. I used to use cv2 with PyPy and it worked well by adding opencv-python.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I am trying to add the libraries by using python 2.7 and pypy but they are not located in venv, just locally on my pc. When I try to add libraries using python 3.7 (located in venv) it let's me without issues. How could I add for example pypy and python 2.7 to venv via Pycharm? It did that automatically when I created a new python interpreter, but I am not sure how to add a new one to venv. That could be the issue correct? Pypy and python 2.7 not being located in venv

Comment: Make sure python 2.7 is in your path. The path for my Base Interpreter when I'm adding a new interpreter in PyCharm is C:\Python27\python.exe

Comment: Could you please share your PyCharm project folder, only PyCharm configurations obviously? I have tried everything as you indicated but the same error keeps popping up, I don't know what else to do. Please.

Comment: guys there is a difference between `PyPy` and `python`!!!

Answer (score 0):

which repo did you clone? The cononical repo for building opencv for python is https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python, but this uses NumPy and will be slow for PyPy.

There is also https://github.com/Magnetic/opencv-cffi which is an incomplete wrapper for a older version of OpenCV. It has an example how to use it https://github.com/Magnetic/opencv-cffi/blob/master/examples/contrast_and_brightness.py